# Architecture for large scale price tracking of all Amazon products

Tags: web-scraping, bigdata

There is a bunch of services that provide price tracking features for Amazon, e.g [Keepa](https://keepa.com). They track around 620 million products on Amazon daily. I was wondering what set of tools do they use to maintain such a large scale tracking? I assume that they use web pages scraping to get their information however, I am not sure how the architecture should look like, so one will not have to pay a couple of millions per month.

Maybe someone here can provide some ideas regarding solutions that might be feasible for such type of challenge.

Comment: Did you check if Amazon offers any consumer apis that return pricing information?

Comment: @RossBush Yes, Amazon Provides Products Advertising API to access Amazon database. However, their daily rates are limited to 8640 per day, which is obviously is not enough.

Comment: I would contact someone in sales for that department. Perhaps they offer more than they advertise for large consumers. I am sorry that I cant offer any hep on scraping, I have never done that.

Comment: @eLRuLL Thank you for your answer. That is a no doubt a large-scale project. I am just interested in tools that are commonly used to retrieve such a huge amount of data. Tools that can provide regular updates of a large set of data but also can be reasonable in price.